# Angular resource timing issue

Tags: angularjs

Folks I have my application setup as below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', []);

myApp.factory('MotorList', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(baseURL + 'MotorList.json', {}, {} );
}]);

myApp.factory('MotorDataManager', function(MotorList) {
 var List;

 MotorList.query().$then(function(value){
   List = value.data;
}) 

return {
  getFullList: function() {
    return List;
  }
  anotherFunction: function { ... }
}

});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,MotorDataManager){
  $scope.tableData  = MotorDataManager.getFullList();
})
```

IN my front-end I have a ng-repeat that loops through $scope.tableData. 
However the issue I am facing is that $scope.tableData never gets rendered. The resource is working fine. It does return data, however I feel this is a timing issue but I am not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Hey, my understanding of angular's .query() function would return the index. Is there a particular reason you had to write your own method?

Comment: Angular's query returns an resource object

Comment: also, could you provide your html template too?

Comment: I noticed as well that you haven't injected the dependency "ngResource"

Comment: This was just a snipped of the code.. it's not that the resource is not working .. the async call works but doesn't get to populating the table in time. The view has nothing other than a ng-repeat to it. I will try and create a plnkr

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, this is a timing issue.  When you call `MotorDataManager.getFullList()`, you are getting `undefined` because the callback which sets it never gets set.  So, `$scope.tableData` is undefined.

You need `$scope.tableData` to have a reference to something that changes.  Here is one way to do it:

```
myApp.factory('MotorDataManager', function(MotorList) {
   var list = [];

   MotorList.query().$then(function(value){
     angular.forEach(value, function(item) {
        list.push(item);
     });
  }); 

  return {
    getFullList: function() {
      return list;
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,MotorDataManager){
  $scope.tableData  = MotorDataManager.getFullList();
});
```

In this example, you are now returning an array, so to start with, `$scope.tableData` will be an empty array.  But that will be OK, because you now have a reference to something.  When the `$resource` returns, it will populate the array (which is the same reference) so your controller will now have a populated array.  Angular's data binding and digestion logic should take care of the rest.

Comment: This doesn't work .. it returns the following error : TypeError: Array.prototype.push called on null or undefined

Comment: Sorry... check out my edit of the `angular.forEach` call.  Whatever the case, that function is just supposed to copy the values into the `list` array, not overwrite it.

Comment: It should, but I don't have a full snippet to work against.  Can you reproduce it on jsFiddle or something like that?